# What is the word or phrase used by french mathematicians for aproximatly equal or `≈`

Tags: mathématiques, typographie

## ≈

What is the word or phrase used by french mathematicians for approximately equal?  `≈`

Comment: Please consult a dictionary and show any kind of research that you have done to find a translation.

Comment: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_de_symboles_math%C3%A9matiques

Answer (score 1):

Cette relation peut se lire de trois façons.

- est approximativement égal à
- est environ égal à
- est à peu près égal à

Les trois expressions sont  aussi utilisés dans la langue courante pour dire la même chose, mais le premier semble l'être  beaucoup plus dans les contextes scientifiques.

[image]

On peut même utiliser « plus ou moins égal à », bien que ce ne soit pas un synonyme standard, et on sera compris, mais dans du texte mathématique assez formel il vaut mieux éviter cette forme.

Comment: Dans un contexte scientifique, on dira aussi "peu différent de".